# This code is supposed to get N values from the user. Then input then into a .txt file

Tags: java, io

This code is supposed to get N values from the user. Then input the values into a .txt file. I'm having trouble getting the values to show in the .txt file. Not sure why.

```
// This program writes data into a file.
import java.io.*; // Needed for File I/O class.
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed for Scanner class.
public class program01
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        int fileName;
        int num;

        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        File fname = new File ("namef.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fname);  // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter ("namef.txt", true);
        PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter("/Users/******/Desktop/namef.txt");

        System.out.println("Enter the number of data (N) you want to store in the file: ");

        int N = input.nextInt(); // numbers from the user through keyboard.
        System.out.println("Enter " + N + " numbers below: ");
        for ( int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        {
            // Enter the numbers into the file.
            input.nextInt();

            outputfile.print(N);
        }
        System.out.println("Data entered into the file.");
        inputFile.close(); // Close the file.
    }
} // End of class
```

Comment: I am sure many people can fix this code. But you should mention what is it that you aren't sure about. And what is it that you have tried already to fix this code.

Comment: When you run this what error do you get?

Comment: @Jim Probably none. OP has PrintWriter, FileWriter and Scanner and is using PrintWriter to write to file but only closing Scanner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your program you seemed to have thrown everything and hoping that it works. To find out what class you should use you should search it in Javadoc of you Java version.
[Javadoc of Java 12](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/index.html)

**PrintWriter:**

> Prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream. This class implements all of the print methods found in PrintStream. It does not contain methods for writing raw bytes, for which a program should use unencoded byte streams.

**FileWriter:**

> Writes text to character files using a default buffer size. Encoding from characters to bytes uses either a specified charset or the platform's default charset.

**Scanner (File source):**

> Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file. Bytes from the file are converted into characters using the underlying platform's default charset.

Now you can see what each class is for. Both PrintWriter and FileWriter are used to write file however PrintWriter offer more formatting options and Scanner(File source) is for reading files not writing files.

---

Since there is already an answer with PrintWriter. I am writing this using FileWriter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // You can provide file object or just file name either would work.
    // If you are going for file name there is no need to create file object
    FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter("namef.txt");
    System.out.print("Enter the number of data (N) you want to store in the file: ");

    int N = input.nextInt(); // numbers from the user through keyboard.
    System.out.println("Enter " + N + " numbers below: ");
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the number into the file: ");
        // Writing the value that nextInt() returned.
        // Doc: Scans the next token of the input as an int.
        outputfile.write(Integer.toString(input.nextInt()) + "\n");
    }
    System.out.println("Data entered into the file.");
    input.close();
    outputfile.close(); // Close the file.
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the number of data (N) you want to store in the file: 2
Enter 2 numbers below: 
Enter the number into the file: 2
Enter the number into the file: 1
Data entered into the file.
```

**File:**

```
2
1
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working variant of what you want to achieve:

```
import java.io.*; // Needed for File I/O class.
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed for Scanner class.

public class program01
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        int fileName;
        int num;

        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        File fname = new File ("path/to/your/file/namef.txt");
        PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter(fname);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of data (N) you want to store in the file: ");

        int N = input.nextInt(); // numbers from the user through keyboard.
        System.out.println("Enter " + N + " numbers below: ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        {
            // Enter the numbers into the file.
            int tmp = input.nextInt();

            outputfile.print(tmp);
        }
        System.out.println("Data entered into the file.");
        outputfile.close(); // Close the file.
    }
}
```

Several comments on above:

1) Got rid of redundant rows:

```
 Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fname);  // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
 FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter ("namef.txt", true);
```

You actually didn't use them at all.

2) In `PrintWriter` we pass `File` object, not `String`.

3) In `for` loop there was a logic mistake - on every iteration you should have written `N` instead of actual number which user entered on console.

4) Another mistake was in closing wrong file in the last line.

**EDIT**: adding according to comment.
in point 2) there's an alternative way - you can skip creating `File` object and pass as a `String` a path to even non-existing file directly in `PrintWriter`, like this:

```
PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter("path/to/your/file/namef.txt");
```

Comment: `PrintWriter` Works with String as well [PrinterWriter doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String))

Comment: @Goion yep, I know that, but I tried to stick to initial code as much as possible, if OP wanted to create a `File` firstly, and then wrap it with `PrintWriter`, then no problem. But I'll add an update regarding it to avoid understatement.

Comment: No worries then. I was just making sure.